# JavaScript string declarations from dynamic data with unescaped quotation marks

Tags: javascript, string, escaping, quotes

I am writing JavaScript templates for a content management system where users fill out text input fields that are passed to my templates.

My problem is the quotation marks in the input fields are not escaped before they are passed to my template, so I have no way of knowing if they will contain single or double quotes, or even both.  Whichever way I try to handle the data my code ends up breaking because the quotes terminate the string declaration.  I want to run a function on the data to escape quotes but I can't find a way to get the data into a valid variable first.

Is there any way to safely handle the data in JavaScript without it breaking a string variable declaration?

Edit: I'm posting code example;

CMS Text Input Field value is: Who'll win our "Big Contest"?

Text Input Field placeholder macro is [%TextInput%]

I'm building an HTML template for this input, using just JS/HTML/CSS

```
<script>
(function(){
  var textInputStr = "[%TextInput%]";
})();
</script>
```

This will break the string declaration if the value of TextInput contains a single quote, and vice versa.

Comment: Encode the HTML so they validly become `&quot;` (or the similar). Then you shouldn't have any problem writing them to an HTML page

Comment: How is the data passed to your javascript templates? It seems like you could simply json encode it(as it is being passed)

Comment: @Ian it sounds like the quotes may also be ending up in JavaScript code, not just HTML.

Comment: @Pointy I understand that, but encoding it should fix that problem. That way you don't have to guess when you do something like `var a = "<?php echo $str; ?>";` whether `$str` contains double quotes or not. And then `a` would be used in templating to be output to HTML. Since the OP is using templates, that implies HTML is being used anyways, so shouldn't the string be encoded? Maybe I'm misunderstanding

Comment: @Ian yes, but HTML encoding may or may not be appropriate. If the string is really just for use by JavaScript, and never appears as text in the DOM, then HTML encoding would be a problem. When the strings are dropped into JavaScript, they should probably just be passed through a JSON encoder. (And I agree of course that the question isn't really clear.)

Comment: The data is passed as a Macro, I write the Macro in my JavaScript and it is resolved as the data string, like this: var myString = '[%Macro%]'; Just no way of knowing whats going to be returned from the Macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an awesome question, and one that deserves an answer. Strings in JS don't have a custom delimiter, like in most other modern languages, so you can get really stuck. But one solution is to build a script tag with the placeholder inside it, then find the innerHTML of that tag and grab the string back into a variable. eg

```
<script id="parseMe" type="text/template">
[%TextInput%]
</script>
```

then use

```
var yourString = document.getElementById("parseMe").innerHTML
```

Now you can manipulate the string as you please.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to run a function on the data to escape quotes but I can't find a way to get the data into a valid variable first.

Well, you will have to make it a valid string literal *before* you could run JavaScript functions on it. There's no other way (unless you count an ajax request to the template script to get a string representation of it).

> The input fields are not escaped before they are passed to my template

Then fix that. There's nothing you can do about it in JavaScript.

Comment: So it sounds like I need to push back and have the backend escape the quotation marks before returning the data.  I couldn't think of any other method but I wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking something obvious.

Comment: Well maybe there's a possibility, depending on how exactly your backend "*passes the input fields to the template*" and how that template is used by JavaScript - you'd need to post that code. But making your backend escape the strings in the first place will definitely be the cleaner solution.

Comment: The JavaScript is served in an HTML template where variables formatted like this: [%%var%%] are populated with the value when the template is served to the page.

Comment: It would be nice if you could [post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17749196/edit) full codes, both the one that is generating the HTML template and the JavaScript that is applying it.